# Nested eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I just started my first laravel project today and stumbled upon this confusing situation,
I intended to use eloquent relationship instead of manually joining tables on query. So here it goes...
I have 3 tables which are `users` , `tbl_instruments_taught` , `tbl_instruments`

> `users` table does not hold any of the table's ID,
>
> `tbl_instruments_taught` - holds the id of user and intruments

**Note: user can teach multiple instruments**

Now, I implemented a `hasOne` on my other result set but I dont think `hasOne` works on this one.
 I read about `belongsToMany` but as I try implement it, it seems like every minute, it gets confusing.

Any idea?

Comment: I would suggest reading docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for pivot table and relation many to many.
You have users table, instruments table (user has many instruments and one instrument could belong to many users) and user_instruments pivot table. Here db model:
[image]

And then add belongsToMany relationship in User and Instrument model (with specified pivot table). Like so:

```
//IN USER MODEL
public function instruments()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Instruments', 'users_instruments', 'user_id', 'instrument_id');
}

//IN INSTRUMENT MODEL
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Users', 'users_instruments', 'insrument_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Now you can reach instruments/users data through laravel relations/eager loading.

Comment: Where do I call the functions?

Comment: You can use it in eager loading like in documentation example: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading